# Measurability question for càglàd process

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I have encounter the following question, which is probably naive for probabilists, but let me still ask it:

Let $\{X_t(\omega): t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ be a real valued càglàd process (that is ''continue à gauche et il existe limite à droite'' instead of the usual càdlàg assumption ), is the following function

$$ \limsup_{t \downarrow 0 } X_t(\omega)$$

measurable? If this is the case, would you please tell me a reference for it, if this is not the case, then what kinds of conditions on the process will such a limit function measurable ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

If $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a càdlàg process, then it follows from the very definition of "càdlàg" that

$$\lim_{t \downarrow 0} X_t(\omega) = \limsup_{t \downarrow 0} X_t(\omega) = X_0(\omega).$$

Consequently, the $\limsup$ is measurable since $\omega \mapsto X_0(\omega)$ is measurable (as $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a stochastic process).

---

**Edit (càglàd case)** If a function $f$ is right-continuous at some point $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then we have

$$\limsup_{y \downarrow x} f(y) = \limsup_{n \to \infty} f(y_n)$$

for any sequence $y_n \downarrow x$. Since the (pointwise) $\limsup$ of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable, we conclude that

$$\limsup_{t \downarrow 0} X_t(\omega) = \limsup_{n \to \infty} X_{t_n}(\omega)$$

is measurable whenever $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a càglàd process. Here $t_n$ denotes an arbitrary sequence satisfying $t_n \downarrow 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And sorry, I made a mistake in my question, the process should be something like: caglad instead of cadlag

Comment: I think one arbitrary $t_n$ does not work. But thanks to Saz's answer, now I think the right argument should be $$\limsup_{t \downarrow 0} X_t(\omega) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{\substack{0< q < 1/n\\ q \in \mathbb{Q}} } X_q(\omega).$$ The equality of course follows from the one-side continuity.

Comment: @YanqiQIU Why does an arbitrary sequence in your oppinion not work?   Sequential (right)continuity is equivalent to (right)continuity.

Comment: Dear saz, since the process in question is not right continuous but only right continuous. (I am sorry that the very first version of my question confused you.)

Comment: @YanqiQIU Well, yes, of course. But to any caglad function $g$ we can associate a cadlag function $g$ by setting $$g(t) = \lim_{s \downarrow t} f(s).$$ And this shows in particular (now using the right-continuity of $g$) that $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} g(t_n) = \limsup_{s \downarrow t} g(s) = g(t)=f(t+).$$

Comment: Yes, this of course works as well.

Comment: @YanqiQIU But this means in particular that the $\limsup$ does not depend on the chosen sequence $(t_n)_n$.

Comment: Yes, I think we can chose a sequence which will work. But probably the next example will show that an arbitrarily chosen will not suffice.

Comment: Yes, I think we can chose a sequence which will work. But probably the next example will show that an arbitrarily chosen sequence $t_n$ does not suffice. Let $f$ be the function defined on the unit interval such that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the function $f$ is linear on the interval $(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}]$ and $$f(\frac{1}{n}) = 0, \quad f(\frac{1}{n+1}+) =1.$$ Of course, this is a left continuous function, and $$\limsup_{t \downarrow 0} f(t) = 1,$$ but $\lim_{n \to \infty} f (\frac{1}{n}) =0$.

Comment: @YanqiQIU But in the given example the (right-hand) limit in $0$ does not exist, i.e. $$\lim_{t \downarrow 0} f(t)$$ does not exist ... and this means that $f$ is not caglad.

Comment: Now, I agree with you. I learned something for our discussion, thank you.

Comment: @YanqiQIU Great. Glad I could help you.